# How to add a header to HTTP request using a filter in JAX-RS?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I'm modifying a`HttpRequest` on my `WebFilter` by adding a single header to `request` using a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` implementation class:

```
HeaderMapRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(request);
requestWrapper.addHeader(OAuth.OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessTokenWord);
chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
```

After `doFilter(requestWrapper, response)` is performed, JAX-RS leads request to its resource, which has a `@RequestScoped` field:

```
@Inject
protected HttpServletRequest request;
```

However, it doesn't contain any expected header:

```
@PostConstruct
protected void initialize_resources() throws IllegalStateException {

    this.currentUser = null;
    String accessToken = this.request.getHeader(OAuth.OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    AccessToken accessToken = this.memcachedResources.getMemcachedAccessTokenRepository()
                                  .get(accessToken);

    if (accessToken != null && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(accessToken.getUser_id())) {
        this.currentUser = this.em.find(User.class, accessToken.getUser_id());
        this.currentClient = accessToken.getClientId();    
    }
}
```

So, `this.request.getHeader(OAuth.OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN)` is `null`.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2811769/1426227) for details on how to add HTTP headers to the request using a servlet filter. If you intend to use a JAX-RS filter, keep reading.

---

### JAX-RS filters

Once you are working with JAX-RS, you'd better using a [`ContainerRequestFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) like the following to add a header to the request:

```
@Provider
public class MyContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.getHeaders().add("header", "value");
    }
}
```

Observe the following:

- The [`ContainerRequestContext#getHeaders()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getHeaders--) returns a *mutable* multivalued map which contains the request headers.
- The [`@Provider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) annotation marks an implementation of an extension interface that should be discoverable by JAX-RS runtime during a provider scanning phase.

For more details about JAX-RS filters, have a look at the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9637). The JAX-RS filters can be applied globally or can be [*name-bound*](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9976) to a subset of endpoints.

### Getting the headers values

In your REST endpoints, you can inject [`HttpHeaders`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html):

```
@Context
HttpHeaders httpHeaders;
```

Then use the [`HttpHeaders` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getHeaders--) to get the header values:

- [`HttpHeaders#getHeaderString(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getHeaderString-java.lang.String-)
- [`HttpHeaders#getRequestHeaders()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getRequestHeaders--)
- [`HttpHeaders#getHeaderString(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getRequestHeader-java.lang.String-)

Comment: What if a legacy application is using JAX-RS 1.1? (The interfaces you mentioned are available from JAX-RS 2.0)

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi perhaps a servlet filter could help in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately even with a servlet filter which wraps requests/responses, the "getheaders" method of the HttpServletRequest gets never invoked. By using @HttpHeaders jax-RS is referring to a different HttpServletRequest (maybe the original one and not the wrapped one, passed with the "doFilter" method)

Comment: NEVERMIND, it worked with filters, just didn't notice that i was passing the original HttpServletRequest instance instead of the wrapped one in the method "doFilter"